# Minimizing viewstate- confused by `EnableViewState` and `ViewStateMode` in asp.net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I'm trying to clean up an older ASP.NET WebForms site that has ViewState enabled everywhere. This is a performance issue - huge viewstates cause noticeable submit delays. But most of the forms don't really seem to need ViewState except for some complex control & form data. Even forms with no input controls, though, generate big viewstates because I guess asp.net is storing all kinds of metatdata about every single server control. But the visibility state, etc, is all controlled in code so I think I can eliminate a lot.

It's pretty onerous to add `EnableViewState="false"` to every single control (in a page and created in code) that doesn't need it, so I'm trying to disable it at a page/control level, and selectively enable it for things that need it. (Yes, I realize this is risky, but there are really just a couple big forms and a couple templates that, if addressed would make a big difference).

Here's what I'm not quite getting.

If a control or page has `EnableViewState="false"` it its `<%.. %>` descriptor, or in its tag where it is created in the parent page, everything breaks, because any ViewState data added in code doesn't work. So I seem to be able to leave it enabled at the control level, but set `EnableViewState` to false for a wrapper control in each container, and then set `ViewStateMode=true` (which ovverrides that) at a per-control level.

What I'm not getting is what happens when:

`ViewStateMode = ViewStateMode.Enabled` and
`EnableViewState = false` for a control that contains other controls.

for a control. Can inner controls be enabled still with `ViewStateMode`?  Basically, which setting has the final word when they conflict?

For each container, I want to be able to disable everything in a wrapper control but still ensure that:

1) **ViewState settings in code work**, and

2) **ViewState is disabled for all controls by default**, and

3) **I can selectively enable ViewState for subcontrols.**

This seems to be confounding. If I have a wrapper control in the master page that is set to `EnableViewState="false"`, but then set a subcontrol to `ViewStateMode="Enabled"`, it breaks. According to MS, ViewStateMode should supercede any outer ViewState settings, yet it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: This question is extremely easy to answer if you give one key piece of information: What version of ASP.NET?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As per the [MSDN article on ViewStateMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstatemode.aspx), `ViewStateMode` only has meaning when `EnableViewState="true"`.  To achieve what you want, you'll have to leave `ViewStateMode="Enabled"` on the control, and then wrap the sub-controls of the main one in an `asp:Placeholder` that has `ViewStateMode="Disabled"`.  That way, you can still manipulate ViewState in the codebehind, but no child control will have ViewState (except the ones you explicitly set to have it via `ViewStateMode="Enabled"`).

Comment: Thanks. I had figured this out after some confusion and have basically set `ViewStateMode="Enabled"` for each control/page, set it `Disabled` for a wrapper, and set it `Enabled` again just for specific controls. Seems to be working so far without too many surprises and the amount of ViewState garbage is noticeably decreased..