# ViewStateMode vs EnableViewState

Tags: c#, asp.net

What's the difference between:

- ViewStateMode: Disabled / Enabled / Inherit
- EnableViewState: True / False

It's in the properties of asp.net controls.

Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: the question is simpler and straight forward to the main point. I have seen similar questions in stackoverflow, but they included too much explanations and examples which are not needed.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**EDIT**

ViewStateMode

- Enabled - Turns the ViewState On for this control
- Disabled - Turns the ViewState Off for this control
- Inherit - Inherits from the value of the parent control

EnableViewState

- Overrides ViewStateMode, must be true for ViewStateMode to have meaning.

See: [Minimizing viewstate- confused by `EnableViewState` and `ViewStateMode` in asp.net 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5485850/402706)

**ORIGINAL**

[Understanding ASP.NET View State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the server control persists its view state, and the view state of any child controls it contains, to the requesting client. [Control.EnableViewState Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.enableviewstate.aspx)
>
> You can use the ViewStateMode property to enable view state for an individual control even if view state is disabled for the page. For more information about view state and control state, see the EnableViewState property.
> [Control.ViewStateMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstatemode.aspx)

Answer (score 8):

The combination allows you to turn off the ViewState for a page as a whole, but enable it for a specific control contained inside.

> To disable view state for a page and
>   to enable it for a specific control on
>   the page, set the EnableViewState
>   property of the page and the control
>   to true, set the ViewStateMode
>   property of the page to Disabled, and
>   set the ViewStateMode property of the
>   control to Enabled.
>
> The default value of the ViewStateMode
>   property for a page is Enabled. The
>   default value of the ViewStateMode
>   property for a Web server control in a
>   page is Inherit. As a result, if you
>   do not set this property at either the
>   page or the control level, the value
>   of the EnableViewState property
>   determines view-state behavior.

From [Control.ViewStateMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstatemode.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Until ASP.NET version 3.5, the page level viewstate control property (EnableViewState) was treated as highest priority, meaning whether the control level property is true or false it doesn't change the behavior, it sees and uses the page level property.
But, in ASP.NET version 4 and onward, the new property (ViewStateMode) is used, which has priority over the page level setting. This allows for more robust conditional settings.

1. Disabled - will disable the viewstate for that page or control(i.e. if the page level property is disabled and control level property is enabled, view state will work for the control).
2. Enabled - will enable the viewstate for that page or control(i.e. if the page level property is enabled and control level property is disabled, view state will not work for the control).
3. Inherit - will inherit the page viewstate property and apply it to the control viewstate property.

Answer (score 0):

[ViewStateMode](http://Control.ViewStateMode%20Property) is used to change the result behavior of setting the [EnableViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.enableviewstate%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) of a page or a control to `true`.

Refering to [Control.ViewStateMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstatemode.aspx)

> The ViewStateMode property of a page
>   or a control has an effect only if the
>   EnableViewState property is set to
>   true. If the EnableViewState property
>   is set to false, view state will be
>   turned off even if the ViewStateMode
>   property is set to Enabled.
>
> The default value of the ViewStateMode
>   property for a page is Enabled. The
>   default value of the ViewStateMode
>   property for a Web server control in a
>   page is Inherit. As a result, if you
>   do not set this property at either the
>   page or the control level, the value
>   of the EnableViewState property
>   determines view-state behavior.
>
> You can use the ViewStateMode property
>   to enable view state for an individual
>   control even if view state is disabled
>   for the page. For more information
>   about view state and control state,
>   see the EnableViewState property.
>
> To disable view state for a page and
>   to enable it for a specific control on
>   the page, set the EnableViewState
>   property of the page and the control
>   to true, set the ViewStateMode
>   property of the page to Disabled, and
>   set the ViewStateMode property of the
>   control to Enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very useful article with a simple detailed example [ASP.Net View State: EnableViewState vs ViewStateMode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asgoyal/archive/2012/08/29/asp-net-view-state-enableviewstate-vs-viewstatemode.aspx). The gist of it is:

> ViewStateMode property allows you to Disable View State at parent
>   level and Enable it selectively at child level.
>
> EnableViewState property does not allow this.
>
> Both of these properties allow you to Enable view state at parent
>   level and Disable it at child level.