# use ViewState with ViewStateMode="Disabled" EnableViewState="true"

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

i use asp.net and this code in aspx page:

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string _Name;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            _Name = "Maikel";
            ViewState["Name"] = _Name;
        }
    }

    protected void btnAddName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ViewState["Name"] == null)
        {
            txtName.Text = "Empty";
        }
        else
        {
            txtName.Text = ViewState["Name"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

its OK. and display "Maikel" in textbox. 
But when I use this code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" **ViewStateMode="Disabled" EnableViewState="true**" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3.Default" %>
```

`ViewState["Name"]` is `Empty`! and display "`Empty`" in textbox. why?

plese help me for use `ViewState` with `ViewStateMode="Disabled" EnableViewState="true"`.

**Edit:**

I use master page and (web from use master page), and write this code in master page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site1.master.cs" ViewStateMode="Disabled" EnableViewState="true" Inherits="WebApplication3.Site1" %>
```

and code `ViewState["Name"]` in code behind page(web from use master page), ViewState is not Empty!! why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469422/viewstatemode-vs-enableviewstate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case you have disabled the ViewState property for the whole page by setting `ViewStateMode="Disabled"` at page level. That is why you are not getting anything in the view state.

[ASP.NET View State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386448%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> To disable view state by default for an entire page, set the
>   ViewStateMode attribute of the @ Page directive to Disabled.

[Control.ViewStateMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstatemode.aspx) *(MSDN)*

> To **disable view state for a page** and to **enable it for a specific
>   control** on the page, set the EnableViewState property of the page
>   and the control to true, set the ViewStateMode property of the page to
>   Disabled, and set the **ViewStateMode property of the control to
>   Enabled.**
>
> The ViewStateMode property of a page or a control has an effect only
>   if the EnableViewState property is set to true. If the EnableViewState
>   property is set to false, view state will be turned off even if the
>   ViewStateMode property is set to Enabled.

**EDIT:**
To Use ViewState in Page.

You can place all your controls inside a panel, and for that panel you can set the ViewState to false. At Page level enable `ViewStateMode` and you will be able to use the ViewState in the code behind

For MasterPage you can disable the ViewState on `ContentPlaceHolder`

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

and at Master page level enable the `ViewStateMode`

Comment: i have numbers control in page. use ViewStateMode="Disabled" at @page for Disabled ViewState All control in page. but i want use ViewState[] in Code. What's the solution?

Comment: @AhmadRezaye, you can place all your controls inside a panel, and for that panel you can set the ViewState to false. At Page level enable ViewStateMode and you will be able to use the ViewState in the code behind

Comment: @AhmadRezaye, why can't you enclose all your controls inside an asp.Net panel and set the viewstate to false for the panel. That will effect the controls inside it.

Comment: @AhmadRezaye, check the edit, In Master page you may disable the viewstate for content placeholder and at page level enable the ViewStateMode

Answer (score 1):

For `EnableViewState="True" ViewStateMode="Disabled"` 
page will not maintain any viewstate i.e  `ViewState["Name"]`

If you need that to be managed, you need to set `EnableViewState="True" ViewStateMode="Enabled"`

Comment: @AhmadRezaye As far as I know, master pages can be thought as a control on Page and disabling their ViewState will have no effect on the page's ViewState.