# How to disable ViewState for a .aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I need to completely disable ViewState for a .aspx page inside my web application. I have gone through different blogs and what I understand is that we must set `<%@ Page EnableViewState="false"  ...%>`, but this is not working.

Is this enough to disable ViewState for all the controls inside the page? Or should I make any additional modifications? If so, please specify them. I don't want the ViewState enabled for even a single control inside the .aspx page

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the quotes should be:

```
EnableViewState="false"
```

Apart from that, if you are still seeing the hidden fields then they are used by ASP.Net. You may see:

[Page.EnableViewState Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableviewstate.aspx)

> Even if EnableViewState is false, the page might contain a hidden view
>   state field that is used by ASP.NET to detect a postback.

Comment: Thanks for reply Habib.  Im actually using EnableViewState="false". It was a spelling mistake in my post

Comment: @MridulRaj, are you still seeing your controls maintaining view state ? because `EnableViewStat = "false"` will disable the view state for the controls, if you are looking at the page source then the hidden fields might be the one used by ASP.net to detect post back

Answer (score 18):

**Disabling View State**

1. **Machine Level** -
       Disabling view state at machine level in [machine.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325473/where-is-machine-config), will disable ViewState of all the applications on the web server.

> ```
> <Machine.config>
>    <system.web>
>       <pages enableViewState="false" />
>    </system.web>
> </Machine.config>
> ```

2. **Application Level** -
   You can disable ViewState for all pages in `/web.config` file.

> ```
> <configuration>
>    <system.web>
>       <pages enableViewState="false" />
>    </system.web>
> </configuration>
> ```

3. **Page Level** - 
      Disabling view state for a specific aspx file at the top.

> `<%@ Page Language="C#" .. EnableViewState="false" .. %>`

4. **Control Level** - You can disable ViewState for a specific control.

> `<asp:TextBox EnableViewState="false" ID="Name"
>   runat="server"></asp:TextBox>`

Comment: Can we mix and match this? For example, can I disable View State at the Page Level and then enable it for a few controls at the control level?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366469/disable-asp-net-viewstate-for-some-controls-but-not-all

Answer (score 3):

If you truly don't need postback, you can remove the form element from your page, this will remove the viewstate entirely.

Comment: Or you just remove the runat="server" attribute from the Form element.

Comment: Fair enough, but why have a form if you are not doing a postback?

Comment: I removed runat="server" as user1176058 suggested and that disabled viewstate and any ASP.NET hidden fields. The form still posts back to the page but the IsPostback flag is not set. The page code has to detect the postback manually.